# normal way of using variables throughout python

Tags: python

What is the standard way of declaring configuration variables for your program at the top of a python script? These are used throughout the program in multiple classes and functions. Is the best way:

1. To create a mixed dictionary with the configuration options, and pass these to any classes that need them. Downside: this requires passing extra attributes. For example:

   ```
   config = {'parseTags': {'title','font','p'},    
       'name': 'steve',                
       'logFrequencies': 10,               
       'print_rate': False  
       }
   ```

   ```
   newCustomObject = CustomClass(config)
   customfunction(config)
   print 'hi',config['name']
   ```
2. Create global variables at the beginning of the file and call those throughout the program. Downside: ruins the encapsulation of the classes.
3. Something else.

What is the most pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: This depends somewhat on the size of your script and how often you need to change the configuration parameters. Is your script small? Will its functions/classes ever be used by other scripts or is it meant to be self contained?

Comment: It's a small 500-line script that fits in a single file. I don't plan to reuse any of the functions elsewhere, but you never know, and but it would be nice to have an elegant solution that follows Object Oriented Programming principles. I don't want to have a separate file with the configuration options, I would like them in the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For constants used in a single file (module), I usually just declare global variables at the top. This does not lose encapsulation in any meaningful way (it's no different from putting those constants in a base class that every class inherits from).

The django config system provides a nice way to create shared constants: you create a module, and the config system creates a read-only object from it, exposing the members of the module.

Comment: The django config example is quite good. There's nothing stopping you from adding config in a python module. However, if you want your settings to be "live" (i.e. changes to a config file have direct impact on a running service which monitors the config file for changes) the py module approach wouldn't work.

Comment: @IoanAlexandruCucu Quite. But neither would the options suggested by OP, so I assume that's not a requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Well, option 1 vs option 2 isn't actually that big of a difference. The dictionary from option 1 is itself global and the values in the dictionary are hardcoded.

I don't know what the most pythonic approach would be, but I would pull the configuration in a separate config file and use python's standard [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) module to read it.

Answer (score 1):

I find it most readable when class is used and configuration options are accessed as its memebers (not instance members), that is:

```
class config:
    option = 3

# code code code
foo = config.opt
```

You can then easily put that out of the file to a module if it gets big and just do `import config from config`.